# Listing FTP contents in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

First off, what my program is doing.
I have a combo box named DirListing and I have the FTP code in to connect to my server. I have an "Update List" button so that once you click it, it lists all the contents in the directory. I want the directory to list, but in the combo box. Here's what I have.

The code for the onClick.

```
private void updateList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string[] listDir = ftpClient.directoryListSimple("/");
   for (int i = 0; i < listDir.Count(); i++)
    {
      DirListing.Items.AddRange(listDir);
    }
 }
```

Here's the directoryListSimple

```
public string[] directoryListSimple(string directory)
        {
            try
            {
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
                string directoryRaw = null;
                try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                ftpReader.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
                try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return new string[] { "" };
        }
```

Of course there's the other FTP information like the actual login information that is above the onClick.

```
ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"server", "user", "password");
```

Whenever I debug the program and click "Update List", the button, all it does is add a blank space to the combo box.

Can anybody help me accomplish my goal of listing the files in my directory in the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i don't get your first code. If i understand it correctly you have an array of string, iterate over each one with this old style for(i=0;i lt x;i++) and on each iteration you add the whole array to your combobox, that means if you have 10 string, you'll add them 10times... not sure it's what you want. This should work :

```
private void updateList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      DirListing.Items.AddRange(ftpClient.directoryListSimple("/"));
}
```

Secondly, when you debug, is the string array filled or not ? I don't think so, for me the issue come from the way you retreive your file listing. Have you got any exception during the ftp request ?

What if you run this code without the try/catch to see exceptions:

```
public string[] directoryListSimple(string directory)
{
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
    ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
    string directoryRaw = null;
    while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) 
    { 
        directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; 
    } 
    ftpReader.Close();
    ftpStream.Close();
    ftpResponse.Close();
    ftpRequest = null;
    return directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray());
}
```

Comment: When I use your code and hit the button it just adds another blank space. Like earlier.
What do you mean by exception?

Comment: You have some try catch in your directoryListSimple (two in a big one surrounding the whole method), perhaps there's an exception thrown during the requests... Is the list returned by the method empty ? If yes, you can be sure it's that and start to check the thrown exceptions

Comment: Yes, it's empty. Every time I click the button. It just adds a blank space to the combo box

Comment: I've edited my first post, test the code i've added, you'll see what's the exception (or put break points in your catch)

Comment: I put in your code and got an error on `ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);` Invalid URI. Was I supposed to do something with this code?

Comment: Yeah, debug it ;) You know what goes wrong now, apparently the uri you provide is not well formatted. [You should take a look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

Comment: How can I format it better? I've looked at that, but I'm trying to figure out where in that page is what I am needing

Comment: Please, take a look at the MSDN/Google/SO first before asking question here :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.95%29.aspx